# jQuery() slower than getElementById

Tags: jquery, performance

I was running some performance tests to see if i could use jQuery directly instead of Ext's wrapper. To start with i wanted to compare jQuery(#id) to doc.getElementById, but i must be doing something wrong, since jQuery(#id) is awful slower.

```
var searchDoc = searchWin.document;
var jqSearchDoc = jQuery(searchWin.document);
for (var i=0; i<500; i++){
    var temp = jqSearchDoc.find('#myID'); //takes 1100ms
    //var temp = jQuery(searchDoc.getElementById('myID')); //takes 3ms
}
```

Any idea why the uncommented line is so much slower? and how to rewrite it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854859/jquery-performance-wise-what-is-faster-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector

Comment: Is `searchWin` not the current window?

Comment: Durilai - thank you.
Nick, searchWin is an adjacent IFrame.

I know getElementById is supposed to be faster, i just didn't anticipate a 100x performance drop off. Also, when i tried Ext.get('myID');  (Ext is the ExtJs library also having element selecting capabilities), it performs exactly like getElementById. Giving me 3ms times.

Answer (score 5):

`getElementById` is a native method. jQuery is not. jQuery does things under the hood to make up for browser inconsistencies. It does `getElementById` after doing regexp matching and whatnot.

Naturally, jQuery is slower because it's a wrap around.

jQuery would be considered fast when compared with other frameworks, since it's a framework. You can't compare a browser native function to a framework that abstracts native methods, native methods will always be faster.