# hide() does not work at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write a script that can hide or show my classes by some considered radio buttons, but it does not work at runtime and does not change dynamically, any ideas?

My script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('addContent').checked) {
            $(".contentForm").show();
            $(".searchContentForm").hide();
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('editContent').checked || 
                       document.getElementById('deleteContent').checked) {
            $(".searchContentForm").show();
            $(".contentForm").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".searchContentForm").hide();
            $(".contentForm").hide();
        }
    });​
```

JsFiddle Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/BpMed/

Comment: Do you know what `||` is? It could simplify your code and eliminate a lot of copy and pasting.

Comment: How can it work at "non"-runtime? Or do you mean it does not work *at all*?

Comment: why are you mixing and matching `getElementById` with jquery?

Comment: Please set up a jsFiddle Demo. Also, `does not work` is not really a problem description we can do anything with.

Comment: @Daniel A. White How can I define my radio buttons without getElementById?

Comment: @iSun - jQuery. $('#addContent') will select it.

Comment: this will only run on load surely....are you trying to catch the radio button clicks? in which case you need to catch the event.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified code:

```
$(".searchContentForm").hide();
$(".contentForm").hide();
$('input[name=tContent]').click(function() {    
    if ($('#addContent').is(':checked')) {
        $(".contentForm").show();
        $(".searchContentForm").hide();
    }
    else if ($('#editContent').is(':checked') || 
             $('#deleteContent').is(':checked')) {
        $(".searchContentForm").show();
        $(".contentForm").hide();
    }
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/KVsrN/)**

​

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
function forDynamic()
{
        if (document.getElementById('addContent').checked) {
            $(".contentForm").show();
            $(".searchContentForm").hide();
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('editContent').checked || 
                       document.getElementById('deleteContent').checked) {
            $(".searchContentForm").show();
            $(".contentForm").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".searchContentForm").hide();
            $(".contentForm").hide();
        }

}
```

Add above code in your javascript. and each update time, you just make a call **forDynamic();**

Answer (score 2):

For one, why are you using `document.getElementById` while using jquery?

You also need to wrap your if block in side of a function that is looking for those radios to be clicked. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7tzw/1/). I added a class of `changeup` to each checkbox, you of course can add whatever you'd like.

```
$(".changeUp").click(function() {
    if ($('#addContent').is(':checked')) {
        $(".contentForm").show();
        $(".searchContentForm").hide();
    }
    else if ($('#editContent').is(':checked')) {
        $(".searchContentForm").show();
        $(".contentForm").hide();
    }
    else if ($('#deleteContent').is(':checked')) {
        $(".searchContentForm").show();
        $(".contentForm").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".searchContentForm").hide();
        $(".contentForm").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Siva Charan's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12747068/237917) is actually better. It's more compact and reduces redundant code. I just wasn't thinking about it enough to have done that

Comment: @Eonasdan, I agree with you regarding getElementById(). However, getElementById() is more faster than the jQuery selector, because it uses Javascript native code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854859/jquery-performance-wise-what-is-faster-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector)

Comment: @LaurentBrieu (almost) everything done with jquery can be done with POJ but jquery is less code and I mean jquery even has $fn.solveWorldHunger() and $fn.PeaceForEveryOne() :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say with so little context, but it looks like this function is only being executed on document.ready - the initial page load.  You need to bind (http://api.jquery.com/bind/) your function to the change event of those checkboxes if you want something more dynamic.

very basic example of something similar:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, but you can use toggle and pass in a condition - so true=show and false=hide - this pretty much gets rid of your duplication inside an if/else statement just to show/hide elements.

```
$(".searchContentForm").hide();
$(".contentForm").hide();
$('input[name=contentMng]').change(function() {   
   var adc =  $('#addContent').is(':checked'); 
   var edc = $('#editContent').is(':checked') ||  $('#deleteContent').is(':checked');
   $(".contentForm").toggle(adc);
   $(".searchContentForm").toggle(edc);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HLmru/

​