# jquery splash screen for editing page information

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of users in an organized table. I want a splash-style div to appear when I click on the row of the user whose information I want to edit. When the splash screen appears, I want to have input boxes within the splash to contain the information of the user. So far I accomplished the splash screen effect. Now the final piece is grabbing the data within the row using the same onclick event as the splash, getting the values of the columns, and changing the innerHTML of the input boxes within the splash.

http://jsfiddle.net/nH6x6/1/

SOLUTION: http://jsfiddle.net/nH6x6/3/

```
<tr class="data" id="row1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Marquezso</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>noob@coder.com</td>
</tr>
```

in the fiddle you have to click on the row to activate the splash.
I want the username and email input fields to contain the data of the clicked row.
In this case row1

=)

Comment: Semantic point: a splash screen is a loading screen, not a popup.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen.  Design point: users orient themselves on web pages based on visual queues.  Making an interface that _hides_ the content of the web page is a bad idea.  Better, would be to convert the content of the `<td>` elements into input boxes themseleves so that the user can edit them "in place" rather than having to reorient and lose access to the content on the screen.  Consider how annoying it would be if you were presented an individual pop-up to edit each cell or row of a spreadsheet.

Comment: Now you're just being pedantic @DanFarrell :P

Comment: @DanFarrell that is a good point. But now you have just raised a new set of jquery questions :)

Comment: Just for fun I threw something together, just to give people some ideas. about how you can tie the data() idea together with the in-place editing I suggest considering.    Also to add my own two cents to the discussion between @CarlMarkham and @ gordon - let's see somebdoy throw this together in 20 or 30 minutes of native JS :)   in jquery, it may not be pretty, but it's easy and very much fast enough.  http://jsfiddle.net/PwtvC/1/

Comment: @DanFarrell havent tested and it is 4am but this could work. No testing and little effort as this is just for fun :P [http://pastebin.com/T7E2AA3a](http://pastebin.com/T7E2AA3a) Undoubtedly some syntax errors and missing methods in there :P

Comment: Looks like you guys are fired up tonight... I have another situation lol :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to reference the relevant `td` element and grab its contents.

For example:

`$('input[name="username"]').val($('#row1 td:first').text());`

I gave a name to your input in the above example as it makes it easier to reference.

Comment: Good point @CarlMarkham - each row will need to be addressed independently.  @MarquézSantos, you'll probably want to give each `<td>` element a class as well ('name', 'email') etc - so that as you add fields or change layout in the future, you can consistently refer tot them as `td.name` and `td.email`.

Comment: You would give each **tr** an id. Then you would have the id as a reference in your `$('.data')` click event. `var id = $(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Good question - but js & html have no way of persistently saving your changes to this data, so your answer lies in another question: Where is this data coming from?  Usually data such as this would be sent from a server application which would pull it from a database or something - perhaps the server application would generate the HTML programmatically, maybe giving each row an ID based on underlying ID from the dataabase, or maybe it would take the more modern appraoch of sending JSON and letting the JS render it.  either way, the _real_ data is stored on the server side.

Comment: Another nice practice when doing this kind of thing is to use JQuery's `.data()` function to store this kind of data - this would be an easy way to store the original input while the user edited for a 'cancel' option, or even multiple versions for rolling back, highlighting change before a commit to the server, and similar features.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I'm struggling to understand how to tie in the ID of the rows with the solution you provided. Can you review my fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/nH6x6/2/

Comment: Updated the fiddle. You were using the `id` as a string rather than a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/76bdx/3/**

Here is a snippet, click fiddle to see everything...

```
//Fill the form
document.getElementById('username').value=$('.data td:nth-child(2)').html();
document.getElementById('email').value=$('.data td:nth-child(4)').html();
```

Gonna have to be a little trickier if your table ever holds more than one user row.  New fiddle on the way for that... {never mind, already answered}

Comment: Why would you mix native Javascript with jQuery?

Comment: native JS is way faster, not that it usually matters.

Comment: But it is better to stick with one or the other rather than a mix of both.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: My favorite thing about `$('#i')` vs `document.getElementById('i')` is that it's so much _shorter_ - but it's also a lot more flexible.  I find that whenever I start mixing like that, I regret it later on when I make changes to my approach and then find that I need additional functionality, causing me to go through and convert to $() selectors later on.  Lesson learned - now, I just do $() straight away.

Comment: @Gordon Basically it is just more consistent and consistency is what every developer needs to use.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree, with the many customers I've worked with and their god awful networks and ancient PCs I go with what's fastest.  Customers don't care about saving a few chars.  But for this answer I simply used getElementById cause I'm amazed how many times I've noticed on stackoverflow that people have learned the jQuery way and have no idea of the native way.  Anyways, native is millions of ops per sec faster in this case: http://jsperf.com/gordon-id   ///   http://stackoverflow.com/a/1855786/3112803

Comment: But we arent talking about clients in this case. I agree, if I make a site for a client I completely skip jQuery and go native, I also agree that people should learn native before jQuery (you need to know what it is doing back there to be a better developer). But I still disagree with mixing jQuery and native. Choose one or the other. In this case the OP chose jQuery.

Comment: Getting into areas of opinion like this will always result in disagreements.  But when it's code I know is in loops or could potentially gain me some speed, then I always run test cases and go with what's fastest.  Sticking with one or the other just cause that's what I started with is a bad idea.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree :P