# JSON Data to HTML with JQuery and native JavaScript which is fastest and optimized

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

As I know we can pass JSON value to HTML using either

```
    document.getElementById("distName").innerHTML= getVar.name;
    $("#distRating").text(getVar.rating);
```

May I know which is the fastest method?

Comment: replacing a single text value yields no performance improvement by either tool. ask the question you really need the answer too. And if you really need to know the answer to that : http://jsperf.com/

Comment: @dbrin I'm building a hybrid mobile app. In this I'm using a CSV data source with fair volume of content and will be converting to JSON and storing it in localStorage with JSON.stringify. As I got fairly large amount of data (less than 3 MB, for mobile) to show in a listview. That's why I'm looking for performance optimization. Anyway, is there any alternative solution to achieve this?

Comment: OK, so put that in your question. Are going to show 30,000 divs to users? are you using libraries already? Are you worried at all about cross browser/platform functionality?

Comment: getElementById will always be faster there are alternatives tho.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854859/jquery-performance-wise-what-is-faster-getelementbyid-or-jquery-selector