# Creating Dynamic Javascript OnClick()

Tags: javascript, html, advanced-custom-fields

I am using [ACF repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) to create user profiles that have a "read more/read less" function that shows and hides text. The issue I'm facing is when I press the "read more" button for the 3rd profile down, it opens the first profile. How do I make this functionality dynamic so it only opens/closes the profile being clicked?

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 60px;">
        <?php if(have_rows('profile')): ?>
        <?php while(have_rows('profile')): the_row(); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="people-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field("profile_img"); ?>')"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h4 class="profile-name">
                        <?php the_sub_field('name'); ?>
                        </h4>
                    <p class="profile-job-title semi-bold">
                                <?php the_sub_field('info'); ?>
                    </p>

                    <p><?php the_sub_field('profile_blurb'); ?><span id="dots">...</span><span id="more"><?php the_sub_field('profile_read_all'); ?></span></p>
                    <div class="about-readmore" onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</div>
                  <div class="readmore-border"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row --> 
    <div class="profile-border"></div>
 <?php
endwhile;
else:
endif;
?>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

#more {display: none;}
```

Comment: HTML IDs must be unique. `document.getElementById("more")` should always return the first `#more` element that is available in the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementById returning value only for first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123707/getelementbyid-returning-value-only-for-first-element)

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
```

You are selecting the *first* occurrence of the element with id = "dots".
That's always the 1st profile in your list.

## 1

One simple way to solve this would be:

1. change the `<div id="dots">` to `<div class="dots">`
2. parameterize this function with a count, then look up the nth
   occurrence of
3. use document.querySelectorAll to look up all ".dots" elements, then
   expand the one using the passed in index to myFunction(index). You can use a php counter var to track index.

   `<div class="about-readmore" onclick="myFunction(index)" id="myBtn">Read more</div>`

## 2

Another, perhaps more fragile way to do it would be to look up and down the DOM to find the nearest profile to expand:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var targetElementParent = event.target.parent;
  var moreText = targetElementParent.querySelector(".more");

  // The rest of the function could remain mostly the same
```

I say this is fragile because it relies on the structure of the DOM pretty heavily so if you change that, the function will break.
In this case, as in #1, you should change the ids "dots", "more" and "myBtn" to classes because those elements are repeated.

From [MDN Id attribute page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document

Answer (score -1):

Ordinarily, you would expect to see that each block of text – each "profile," as you call them – would have a unique `id` in the HTML/DOM. Let's say for the sake of example that the `id` of one of the blocks is "123."  The HTML for *that* profile would then be generated to contain `onclick="myFunction(123)"`.

Now, each `onClick` is different – it supplies the `id` that the function is supposed to act upon, and this function should *always* see that `getElementById` returns a valid object because an element with that `id` should always be present.  *(If it doesn't, there's a bug in the generated HTML, and it should complain.)*