# Selecting each of automatically generated by server .div by class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, dom-manipulation

Serious noob question. I'm using node.js and handlebars. I'm using handlebar's {{#each}} to generate a .div for each post in my database. Problem is, when I use below document.getElement in my client-side main.js file it's only getting the first post. Please help me to get it working regardless of how many posts there are. Thank you!

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
document.getElementById('grabMe').classList.toggle("rotate");
```

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementById returning value only for first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123707/getelementbyid-returning-value-only-for-first-element)

Comment: Yep, as others have mentioned, IDs are meant to be assigned to a single element. Instead of creating multiple elements with the same ID, consider using a `class` instead. So if you output `<div class="dropdown"></div>` within your `{{#each}}` loop, then running `document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')` will return a NodeList that contains all your dropdown divs.